# List Academic Credentials in the cover letter signature?

Tags: job-search, human-resources, cover-letter, signatures

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90241/how-should-degrees-be-listed-in-an-e-mail-signature/90245

I am trying to list my academic credentials as a signature at the bottom of my cover letter. I came across the link above but he has degrees in different subjects while I have different degrees in the same subject.
I have PhD, MSc and BSc in Petroleum Engineering. Do I write:

`Dr. AA`

`PhD, MSc, BSc in Petroleum Engineering`

or

`Dr. AA`

`PhD, MSc, BSc`

Or

`AA, PhD, MSc, BSc`

Also, `do you list the societies that you are member of or not?`

Thanks

Comment: Just listing your Ph.D. should be enough. It's implied that you also have a Bachelors and probably a Masters. What kind of societies are you referring to? Associations like ACM, IEEE, etc., I'd say no.

Comment: I just list my Ph.D. The rest is implied anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a hiring manager, I don't honestly care very much about anything other than your highest degree. Just list one and move on - the only purpose of a CV and a cover letter is to get you an in-person interview.

And unless they're actually relevant to the job you're applying for, I really, really don't care about which societies you are in. They don't have any bearing on how well you're going to do your job.

(Although hopefully you won't use `monospaced fonts` in the middle of your cover letter; that looks unprofessional).

Comment: Would you please explain what do you mean by `monospaced fonts`? Google is giving me Examples of monospaced fonts include Courier, Lucida Console, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, Inconsolata and Source Code Pro. is that what you mean ?